# Metadata file .dll could not be found AND Value cannot be null (Parameter name: key) ERRORS popping up while working on Xamarin cross-platform app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, mobile

Hi everyone I was doing a simple Xamarin cross-paltform app and suddendly the error ***Value cannot be null parameter name: key*** appered pointing to the 1st line of one of the xaml files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="PracticaMastDet.afterSignUpPage">

    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Green" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Grid Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RowDefinitions="*,*,*" ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*">
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Turquoise" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Pink" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Lime" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Orange" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="MediumPurple" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkMagenta" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="Maroon" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="DeepPink" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

I tought it was a bug of Visual Studio because there's clearly not an error in that line but when I restarted the IDE and clean and build the solution another error popped up: ***Metadata file .dll could not be found***.
After that I have searched a lot around the internet but could not  figure it out, can someone please help me?

Comment: Try to delete bin/obj folder under each project then clean and rebuild again. Does you project installed any third-part Nuget packages?

Comment: Not working @JackHua-MSFT this thing its pretty weird. No, my project does not have installed third-part Nuget packages, just the Nuget packages included with the cross-platform app VS template. I also started another solution yesterday and after some time the <<metadata file .dll could not be found>> error also popped up in the new proyect, don't really know if is related.

Comment: Are you using the latest Visual-Studio?

Comment: Yes I have the latest version.

Comment: I would recommend you to repair or re-install your visual-studio.